# Headless torrent client that has a web interface with RSS support

Tags: linux, web-apps, rss, bittorrent

I have checked TransmissionBT, uTorrent, qBittorrent and Deluge. Some of them offer RSS support, Deluge has a plugin, but none of them seem to offer it via the web interface. I have a headless server so I absolutely need this to be in the web interface.

A potential option is if the daemon accepts GUI connections from a desktop that will allow me to configure RSS which will then run headless once I disconnect. I think Deluge could do remote GUI connections IIRC?

This is for Linux (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS).

Comment: There are paid bitorrent clients worth their name? I will consider anything. And yes, linux.

Comment: I don't know if there are – but in case of, that might be relevant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i went with Deluge. I installed YaRSS via the RPC client on PC which worked.